# JGIT: git checkout --

Tags: java, jgit

I have a not staged modified file and I would like to discard the changes.

In git it would be something like

```
git checkout -- .
```

How can I emulate this behavior with JGit ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To revert a single file, you could use the CleanCommand:

```
Set<String> paths = new HashSet<String>();
paths.add( ... );
git.clean().setPaths( paths ).call();
```

Unfortunately there is a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=431392) that prevents the CleanCommand to reset files in sub-directories.

If I interpret the '.' in `git checkout -- .` correctly you want to revert all changes in the work directory. The ResetCommand does that:

```
git.reset().setMode( ResetType.HARD ).call();
```

This would also override the index with the contents from HEAD.

If you don't care about the index, you could also read the file-contents from the HEAD commit and write them to the work directory yourself. Let me know if that is of interest for you and I will try to assemble a snippet that does so.